# get multiple strings from .txt then output toghether

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I have a test.txt with this text:

```
<game>16t (Japan)</game>
<manufacturer>Sega</manufacturer>
<game>3 Ninjas Kick Back</game>
<manufacturer>Malibu</manufacturer>
```

I'm trying to write a batch file that will output extracted strings to another .txt with the following pattern:

```
game: 16t (Japan)
developer: Sega

game: 3 Ninjas Kick Back
developer: Malibu
```

My code:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2 delims=>" %%a in ('findstr "<game>" test.txt') do echo game: %%a >> "%~dp0/output.txt"
for /F "tokens=2 delims=>" %%b in ('findstr "<manufacturer>" test.txt') do echo developer: %%b >> "%~dp0/output.txt"
```

But my generated output.txt comes out like this:

```
game: 16t (Japan) 
game: 3 Ninjas Kick Back 
developer: Sega
developer: Malibu
```

How can I achieve the intended output pattern?

Comment: Is awk an option?

Comment: `awk` only exists by default on Linux boxes. You're gonna have a bad time if you try to go that route on a Windows box.

Comment: Yes, that's what i thought. Wasn't sure tho. I also have Linux installed. Might aswell try it. Thank you.

Comment: The `findstr` command just searches strings and returns lines that contain a match, it is not capable of altering the lines of text…

Comment: The `findstr` command can search for more than one string at a time. Knowing that information and using the correct amount of tokens and delimiters you can use an IF command to determine which search string it found and output the lines accordingly.

Comment: @Squashman Yes, you are right. The problem is this is only a simple example. My actual code has a few strings that need to be found with different delimiters, so i'm not sure how can i tell the findstr to find more than one string using different delimiters.

Comment: I found an easy workaround, which is to find the different delims first (as strings), then make them the same as the others. And then i can find all the strings with the same delims (in this case, <>). But i don't think that's efficient at all. I'll figure it out, just a matter of trial and error, till i find the right syntaxes. Back to reading the docs i guess. Thank you all.

Comment: Simple with hybrid batch/JScript [jrepl.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044).  `jrepl "<game>(.*)</game>.*|<manufacturer>(.*?)</manufacturer>.*" "game: $2|developer: $4\n" /a /b /t "|" /xseq /f test.txt`. There are many other ways to do the same with JREPL, but that was the first that came to mind.

Comment: I forgot - add `\o output.txt` to write the result to a file, or `\o -` to overwrite the original file.

Comment: I implore you to go back and take the [tour] like it was requested when you joined StackOverFlow.  Then read [ask] a good question.  When posting questions you should always provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your input and the code you are using.  People don't like writing code for one specific example and then have to completely change it when you change the technical specifications.  That is called SCOPE CREEP and programmers hate that with a passion!

Comment: If it is a properly formatted XML file your best bet would be to use a scripting language that has a native method to read and write XML.  Windows has three scripting languages by default that you could use.  VBscript, Jscript or Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

As Squashman mentioned in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69384613/get-multiple-strings-from-txt-then-output-toghether#comment122642402_69384613), and based upon the exact format you've submitted as your input file contect, there is a much simpler way of doing it:

Single line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) example

```sh
@(For /F "Tokens=1-2 Delims=<>" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IR "<Game> <Manufacturer>" "test.txt" 2^>NUL') Do @If /I "%%G" == "manufacturer" (Echo %%G: %%H& Echo() Else Echo %%G: %%H) 1>"%~dp0output.txt"
```